# Regex to return all number strings except specific number string

Tags: regex

what should be the regex which gives me all the strings with all the numbers except 31 in it?

For example my string is something like:

```
td33p01if-dlb030s
td33p01if-dlb031s
td33p01if-dlb032s
td33p01if-dlb033s
td33p01if-dlb034s
td33p01if-dlb001s
td33p01if-dlb072s
td33p01if-dlb073s
```

Regex should be such that it will not return string `td33p01if-dlb031s` because it contains 31 in it. Apart from this all number strings are fine.

something like this - `td33p01if-dlb0[^31]s`

I know it's wrong. But i want something like this it seems.

Comment: What language/tool/library are you using?

Comment: If your regex engine supports lookaheads, you can use something like [`td33p01if-dlb0(?!.*31)\d+s`](https://regex101.com/r/xNqiFT/1).

Answer (score 0):

Your regex `td33p01if-dlb0[^31]s` using a negated [character class](https://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html) `[^31]` which will match not 3 and not 1. That would for example match `td33p01if-dlb0Ws`

If what follows should be 2 digits but not 31, you could use a negative [lookahead](https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) `(?!31)` to assert that what is on the right side is not 31 and then match 2 digits `\d{2}` followed by `s`:

`^td33p01if-dlb0(?!31)\d{2}s$`

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/dTY7gc/1)

Another option could be to specify a range from 00 - 99 not matching 31 using a non capturing group with an [alternation](https://www.regular-expressions.info/alternation.html):

`^td33p01if-dlb0(?:[0-2][0-9]|30|3[2-9]|[4-9][0-9])s$`

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/3tVFMC/1)

Answer (score 0):

Use a negative look ahead:

```
td33p01if-dlb((?!31)\d)+s
```